# SQL Server removes multiple if statement using Case or other means

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

These are some of the bit values that I am passing to my stored procedure and based on these values my where clause is being generated

```
@booking bit,
@drs bit,
@manifest bit,
@receiving bit,
@status bit
```

Its very simple like

```
if (@booking=0)
Select * from Table where ColumnName='Booking'
if (@drs=1)
Select * from Table where ColumnName=DRS'
--so on based on other bit values
```

Query remains same but based on the bit value I get the result set and merge the result sets.

In a simple day this query looks like this

```
Select * from Table where ColumnName in ('Booking','DRS')
```

I don't want multiple if statements in my stored procedure and make it in a single query by any means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `OR` statements between the options and `AND` the name that you are searching for with the bit that enables it.

```
Select * from Table
where (   (ColumnName='DRS' AND @drs = 1)
       OR (ColumnName='Booking' AND @booking = 1)
       OR (ColumnName='Manifest' AND @manifest = 1) 
       OR (ColumnName='Receiving' AND @receiving = 1) 
       OR (ColumnName='Status' AND @status = 1)
      )
```

---

As Aaron points out in the comments this may hurt your performance depending on how the query plan was generated.

Comment: Just use caution because you will only get a single query plan for this pattern, and it might not be the best one for the job depending on the skew of the values in `ColumnName`. For example, if `'DRS'` appears in the table once, and `'Booking'` appears in the table 600,000 times, two very different plans will likely be most effective for each of those results... but the plan you'll get for both will depend on the plan that happened to be generated first.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Very true! would using separate queries using `union` to join them solve that problem or would it be better to load in to a temporary table?

Comment: Actually I think dynamic SQL is the best option. For these OR/OR/OR patterns with different parameters, the UNION will do the same thing (and I hope you meant UNION ALL :-)) And the temp table can sometimes help but it's a lot of guaranteed I/O every time. With dynamic SQL you can prevent cache bloat by using `optimize for ad hoc workloads` and you can still beat parameter sniffing using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If you posted a solution like that I would upvote it :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is dynamic SQL. It can prevent the issue I mentioned against Scott's answer:

> Just use caution because you will only get a single query plan for this pattern, and it might not be the best one for the job depending on the skew of the values in ColumnName. For example, if 'DRS' appears in the table once, and 'Booking' appears in the table 600,000 times, two very different plans will likely be most effective for each of those results... but the plan you'll get for both will depend on the plan that happened to be generated first.

With dynamic SQL you can prevent cache bloat by using the `optimize for ad hoc workloads` server setting (assuming SQL Server 2008+) and you can still beat parameter sniffing using `OPTION (RECOMPILE)`. Here is a quick example:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @sql = N'SELECT columns -- never use * in production
  FROM dbo.Table -- always use schema prefix
  WHERE ColumnName = @param OPTION (RECOMPILE);';

DECLARE @param VARCHAR(32);

SET @param = CASE WHEN @drs       = 1 THEN 'DRS'
                  WHEN @booking   = 1 THEN 'Booking'
                  WHEN @manifest  = 1 THEN 'Manifest'
                  WHEN @receiving = 1 THEN 'Receiving'
                  WHEN @status    = 1 THEN 'Status' 
END;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@param VARCHAR(32)', @param;
```

It's uglier and harder to maintain, but it has far less chance of sticking you with a terrible plan (and bouts of terrible performance as a result).